# Can I use Ubuntu One to sync data fiies between two remote computers

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've got two computers,  both running Ubuntu with files in their home folders sync'd in to Ubuntu One.   I'd like to know if it's possible to make Ubuntu One automatically download data changes that have been uploaded automatically to Ubuntu One from one computer to the equivalent data file in the other.

Clarifying a bit further,  I've installed Red Notebook in both computers and so they each have their own /.rednotebook/data folder containing a series of .txt files corresponding to the monthly entries in each of them.  These are sync'd to upload any changes to those .txt files to Ubuntu One.   My question is can I,  and if so how,  do I make Ubuntu One automatically download and replace those .txt files in the other computer after they've been updated and uploaded from the first computer?

I did labouriously manage to download all those text files which had been uploaded from the first computer,  from Ubuntu One  one-by-one to the second computer,  but what I want to do is automate this process and that's where I'm stuck.

I'm aware that things could get a bit complicated if both my computers were on-line at the same time and both were simultaneously making different Red Notebook entries,  so that's not the scenario I'm trying to cover.   All I want to achieve is that whatever updates to the files have been uploaded by one computer,  will automatically be downloaded to the same-named files in the other computer as soon as that second computer appears on line and detects that Ubuntu One has matching but more recent sync'd files than the ones it's holding.

Answer (score 2):

If the folders are synchronized on both computers, and thus subscribed on both computers, then Ubuntu One will keep them in sync, while they are connected to the service. This is exactly what Ubuntu One is designed and built to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be possible.

Just select Sync Locally for the folder `/.rednotebook/data`  in the Ubuntu One Clients of both the systems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntuone doesn't exist anymore, to sync your data with dropbox example:

`ln -s ~/.rednotebook/data/ ~/Dropbox/rednotebookdata`

It will create rednotebookdata link name to rednotebook data folder, and will sync automatically.

It will help you a lot to sync with any other cloud sync client because you just need to change the link name  location.